# Credit card hijack

Tags: magento-1.7, security

I have an installation of magento 1.7.3

I tried both patching and upgrading my magento to 1.9.3,but magereport still shows that the patch supee8788 is not applied, and credit card hijack detected. How can I solve these issues?

Comment: Hi, you might be interested in this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121962/231

Comment: Long story short: You need to do some serious cleanup, best would be to do a clean install on a new server with files and a database where you can be sure they're not still compromised. And get some external help from an experienced Magento developer/agency.

Answer (score 0):

We went into the Design/Footer HTML part from the admin, and sure enough found a malicious script which was causing the problems. Removed it and patched the code and the report looks fine now.